# Issue around the 'elim restriction'

Tags: coq

I am currently going through the book 'Computational Type Theory and Interactive Theorem Proving with Coq' by Gert Smolka, and on page 93, the following inductive predicate is defined:

```
Inductive G (f:nat -> bool) : nat -> Prop :=
| mkG : forall (n:nat), (f n = false -> G f (S n)) -> G f n
.
```

Then on page 95 it is argued that one can define an eliminator:

```
Definition elimG : forall (f:nat -> bool) (p:nat -> Type),
    (forall (n:nat), (f n = false -> p (S n)) -> p n) ->
    forall (n:nat), G f n -> p n.
Proof.
...
```

The book spells out an expression of a term of this type, namely:

`elimG f p g n (mkG _ _ h) := g n (λe. elimG f p g (S n) (h e))`

(I have changed a few notations for the purpose of this post)

which I formally translated as:

```
refine (
    fun (f:nat -> bool) (p:nat -> Type) =>
        fun (H1:forall (n:nat), (f n = false -> p (S n)) -> p n) =>
            fun (n:nat) (H2:G f n) =>
                match H2 with
                | mkG _ _ H3  => _
                end
).
```

However, Coq will not allow me to carry out the pattern match due to the elim restriction.
The book informally says "Checking that the defining equation of `elimG` is well-typed is not difficult"

I am posting this in the hope that someone familiar with the book will have an opinion as to whether the author made a mistake, or whether I am missing something.

**EDIT:**
Having played around with the two answers below, the simplest term expression I have come up with is as follows:

```
Definition elimG 
    (f:nat -> bool) 
    (p:nat -> Type)
    (g: forall (n:nat), (f n = false -> p (S n)) -> p n)
    : forall (n:nat), G f n -> p n 
    := fix k (n:nat) (H:G f n) : p n := g n 
        (fun e => k (S n) 
            ( match H with
              | mkG _ _ H => H
              end e)).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definition is possible, there's just a subtlety here. The `G` (which is in `Prop`) is never needed to make a *decision* here, because it only has one constructor. So you just do the

```
elimG f p g n h := g n (λe. elimG f p g (S n) _)
```

"unconditionally" *outside* of any `match` on `h`. That hole now has expected type `G f (S n)`, which now is in `Prop`, and we can do our `match` on `h` there. We also have to do some rewriting shenanigans with the `match`. Putting everything together, we write

```
Fixpoint elimG
  (f : nat -> bool) (p : nat -> Type)
  (g : forall (n:nat), (f n = false -> p (S n)) -> p n)
  (n : nat) (H : G f n) {struct H}
  : p n :=
  g n
   (fun e =>
      elimG f p g (S n)
       (match H in G _ n return f n = false -> G f (S n) with (* in and return clause can be inferred; we're rewriting the n in e's type *)
        | mkG _ _ H => H
        end e)).
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a tricky one.
The author is not wrong, it is possible to define such an elimination principle but you have to be careful about how and when you match on your hypothesis.

The error that you get from Coq is that you are matching on a proposition to build an element of a Type. Coq forbid this so that proposition can be erased when extracting code, so you cannot do such a case-analysis of a proposition to build some computationally meaningful object (there are exceptions to this rule for instance for empty propositions).

Since you cannot start by pattern matching on `H2`, you can try to push this case-analysis as late as possible. Here you only need to do the case analysis in the application `(h e)` so you could replace it by `match H2 with mkG _ n' h -> h e end`.

However this does not work because `h` is of type `f' n' = false -> ...` whereas `e : f n = false` and you need to explain to Coq that `n` and `n'` are the same. This is achieved through dependent pattern matching, putting the apllication outside of the match and using a `return` clause in the script below (actually Coq can infer this return clause, I'm just leaving it for explanations).

```
Inductive G (f:nat -> bool) : nat -> Prop :=
| mkG : forall (n:nat), (f n = false -> G f (S n)) -> G f n
.

Fixpoint elimG (f:nat -> bool) (p:nat -> Type)
         (g : forall (n:nat), (f n = false -> p (S n)) -> p n)
         (n:nat) (H : G f n) {struct H} : p n.
Proof.
  refine (g n (fun e => elimG f p g (S n) _)).
  refine (match H in G _ n0 return f n0 = false -> G f (S n0) with mkG _ _ h => h end e).
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kyo. Your answer also has a lot a valuable insight which I am grateful for. It is the second answer I got but I cannot honestly say that it was less helpful than the first.